# MySQL High Availability with VMWare/DRBD/Heartbeat still common practice?

Tags: mysql, vmware-esx, high-availability

Is it still common practice to use a DRBD/Heartbeat solution for a high available MySQL Instance when the whole environment is virtualized (in our Case VMWare)
Are there other/better solutions out there to achieve similar results?

For us running built-in VMWare tools like HA or Fault Toleration are not an option.

Thanks!

Comment: Why isn't VMware HA an option? What are you trying to protect against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of HA do you need?

- If it is  at first consistency (durability) than DRBD with Pacemaker or SAN is your choice. Also take a look at Percona XtraDB Cluster (synchronous replication, but InnoDB tables only);
- If it is about read availability (reads are important then writes) then you can use Pacemaker + VIP + mysqlping cluster resource (https://github.com/Sov1et/ocf-mysqlping).